# How to use universal link with flutter uni_link

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-universal-links

I am developing an app using `universal link` and `app link`.
You are enrolled in the apple developer program.

**how i tried**

- Register `Associated Domains`.
  [image]
- Modify `Info.plist`

```
...
<dict>
      <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
      <string>Editor</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
      <string>m.mydomain.com</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>https</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
...
```

- Create an `apple-app-site-association` file (I did not append it to the .json name)

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "<TeamID>.<Bundle Identifier>",
                "paths": ["/test/connect.asp"]
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Android works normally, but `Universal link` does not work in IOS.